# Dismantling glued speaker cabinet

Tags: adhesive

I own this Infinity satellite surrounding speakers and few days ago one of it rattles like its voice coil come loose and rubbing the magnetic gap.

I wanted to dismantle its cabinet to change the speaker driver but unfortunately this cabinet looks like glued.

I appreciate any information on how to get this thing opened with minimum or no damage on its surface.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about a pic from the front? I have repaired speaker cones on several occasions and have always accessed them from the front side.

Comment: I have loaded the picture from the front. Should I pry open the metal grill? My concern is the dents might be very obvious..

Comment: IMO you should *gently* pry up the metal grill around its perimeter, it is likely that it's just pressed into place. You should find the speaker units attached to a face-board with screws, and will be removable from the front for servicing/replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try to pull it using wire hook, hopefully it come out easily.

Comment: You might try a hair dryer to warm up any glue before prying.

Comment: You guys should put these as the answers so I can vote them up.

Comment: Let us know how it works out, I can change the comment to an answer. Most important is you have a chance to fix your speaker